# how to add dynamic input data to data of $http in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http

> I have a form which has input boxes generated dynamically, now how can I add the dynamic form data to the data of $http in angularjs?

controller code:

```
app.controller('saveQues', function ($scope, $http, $location){
                $scope.insertData=function(){
                    $http({
                        url: "savequestions.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: #how to add here,
                        headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        }
                    }).then(function(response){
                        console.log('then');
                    }).catch(function(response) {
                      console.error('Gists error', response.status, response.data);
                    })
                    .finally(function() {
                      console.log("finally finished gists");
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model in the view to bind that input to the data in the controller and then call the http post on click of a button.

In the view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="toBind"></div>
```

In the model:

```
 $scope.insertData=function(){
                $http({
                    url: "savequestions.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $scope.toBind,
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log('then');
                }).catch(function(response) {
                  console.error('Gists error', response.status, response.data);
                })
                .finally(function() {
                  console.log("finally finished gists");
                });
```

Comment: For single input box it would work but what if there are some n number of input boxes which are dynamically generated using a loop?

Now how to bind all those inputs to data in the controller?